# Close libreoffice document from command line

Tags: ssh, libreoffice

I have an opened libreoffice document on a remote computer. I have an SSH access to this computer but no physical access. I can access this document through SSH, but I forgot to save it when I left.

How could I remotly close the currently running libreoffice instance on the remote computer and save the document ?

Here are the libreoffice related processus running

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i libreoffice
xxxx     27763 26307  0 13:15 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i libreoffice
xxxx     30103 30100  0 déc.22 ?      00:00:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash
xxxx     30135 30103  0 déc.22 ?      00:00:29 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
```

Comment: does [this reference](https://superuser.com/q/1102630/856934) from superuser give any assistance?

Comment: Almost, I have no idea about the name of the window I have...  I've searched for the name of my document with and without extension but got "Error: Can't open display: (null)"

Comment: What is the output of `ps -ef | grep -i libreoffice`?

Comment: Added the running processus in the question.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, if you can't get the brilliant solution using 'xdotool' to work. By default LibreOffice autosaves documents. You could investigate where these autosaves are stored, `kill soffice.bin` via ssh and then directly access the autosave.

Comment: Use `x11vnc` and connect to the X-server via `vncviewer`.